# Deterministic Finite Automata divisibility problem

Tags: automata, dfa

Design a DFA that accepts the string given by **L = { w has number of 'a' divisible by 3 and number of 'b' divisible by 2 over the alphabet `{a,b}` }**

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck with your attempted solution?

Comment: @Welbog i am not getting any idea about it , could u just show me the transition states of the given dfa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize that we should have 3 * 2 = 6 states in the DFA. Why? Because one has 3 choices for the number of a's (0 or 1 or 2) [*think in terms of* ***remainders***] and 2 choices for number of b's (0 or 1 similarly).

Let us name the states **`axby`** which means I have found **`x`** number of a's and **`y`** number of b's till now. For example, if we are in `a2b0` and we encounter an `a`, then we go to `a0b0` (hope you see why?). Similarly `a1b1` ---<sup>b</sup>---> `a1b0` and `a1b1` ---<sup>a</sup>---> `a2b1`.
Needless to say `a0b0` is the accepting state.

Now, all you have to do is draw the states and keep joining them. I have drawn them on a paper here.

[image: Answer]